# Не могу подключится к сервису WCF в локальной сети

Tags: c#, wcf

Здравствуйте. Возникла необходимость изучать WCF. Написал простое тестовое приложение и по Ip адресу компьютера решил разместить сервис.
использую 2 конечные точки: одну основную и одну mex для метаданных.
С того же компьютера, где размещен сервис выполнил коннект для проверки с помощью "WCFTestClient". Коннект прошел успешно и сервис работает.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Далее запустил "WCFTestClient" на ноутбуке помещенном в общую сеть (с ноутбука проходит пинг компа 192.168.1.33). Попытался подключиться к сервису и вылезла ошибка "Не могу добавить сервис. Метаданные сервиса не доступны. ..."

брэндмаур на ноуте отключен. на ноуте стоит Win7. на компе Win10 и насчет брэндмауэра не знаю
Подскажите что делаю не так?
Это ошибки в настройках сервиса или нужно настаивать компы?

```
  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="WcfCalcService.CalcService">
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress = "http://192.168.1.33:50000/Service"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>

        <endpoint address="Calc" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="CalcLibrary.Contract.ICalcService">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost"/>
          </identity>
        </endpoint>

        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True" httpsGetEnabled="True"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>

</configuration>
```

Comment: Если при запущенном сервисе открыть в браузере `http://192.168.1.33:50000/Service?wsdl` - что выведет?

Answer (score -1):

Ребят вопрос был в настройках брэндмауэра компа с запущенным сервисом.
Прошу прощения за беспокойство.

Есть еше вопрос. когда запускаю тестовый пример с VS2015 то при запуске сервиса запускается WcfSvcHost.exe и там отображается статус запущенного сервиса.

Когда вставил использую сервис в реальном приложении то все работает но WcfSvcHost.exe не вызывается. Почему? и как его вызвать в ручную например?

Comment: Пожалуйста, не задавайте новых вопросов под видом ответов. Ответы на вопрос сделаны не для этого.

Comment: Хорошо учту на будущее ((